# How to use delegates between UIViewControllers?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have already scoured:

- [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)
- [Passing data between two ViewControllers (delegate) - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075116/passing-data-between-two-viewcontrollers-delegate-swift)
- [Reload collection view data from another view class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879092/reload-collection-view-data-from-another-view-class)

But could not find an answer. Basically I have two view controllers and am trying to use a delegate to update an array and eventually reload the collectionview.

**ViewController1**

```
    class ViewController1: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, AppendDelegate {

    let cellID = "cell"

    var list = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
    let otherView = ViewController2()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        otherView.delegate = self
        print(list)

        let collection = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds)
        collection.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
        collection.delegate = self
        collection.dataSource = self
        collection.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(collection)

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(moveToOtherVC))
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        return cell
    }

    func appendItem(string: String) {
        list.append(string)
        print(list)
    }

    @objc func moveToOtherVC() {
        let VC2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController2())
        present(VC2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**My second view controller**

```
    protocol AppendDelegate {
    func appendItem(string: String)
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var delegate: AppendDelegate?

    let textField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 39, height: 20))
        tf.backgroundColor = .blue
        return tf
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(textField)

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(sendDataToCollection))

        textField.center.x = view.center.x
        textField.center.y = view.center.y
    }

    @objc func sendDataToCollection() {
        guard let text = textField.text else {return}
        self.delegate?.appendItem(string: text)
        textField.text = ""
        moveToVC()
    }

    @objc func moveToVC() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

In the second class, shouldn't self.delegate.appendItem result In ViewController1 appending to the list?

I have also used Notification Center as an alternative to delegates but found no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing almost everything right, but you're setting your `ViewController2`'s delegate wrong.

You're actually setting delegate of new instance of `ViewController2` in `viewDidLoad` but in `moveToOtherVC` you're presenting different `ViewController2` as root of `UINavigationController`

Instead set delegate of new instance of `ViewController2` and use this instance as `rootViewController` of presenting `navigationController`

```
@objc func moveToOtherVC() {
    let vc2 = ViewController2()
    vc2.delegate = self
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)
    present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

or you can solve your problem just with passing `otherView` as `rootViewController` of `navigationController`

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: otherView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewController1 func like this-

```
  @objc func moveToOtherVC() {
     let otherView = 
     self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
     "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
     otherView.delegate = self                                
     self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Comment: He’s not using storyboard